# Command Options on Command Line - Details and Functions?

Tags: command-line

I can see there are a lot of command line options in Ubuntu.

For example: the `-l` and `-v` options in `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo shred /dev/sdb1 -v` .

Does anyone know where I can find all of the options with their functions?

I've used many commands, these make sense, but the commands' options do not. I would like to know about them.

Comment: I have no clue what you are looking for, and I am afraid I am not the only one. Could you explain what is your goal?

Comment: No i mean: you have one command with the iteration -l and another with the same -l. What do these mean? What does the l or v or any letter stand for in command lines? How do i know which one to use in commands?

Comment: Ah, I think you are not using the word iteration correctly :). The options and their meaning depends on the application (command). run in a terminal e.g. `man ls`, there you see what you are looking for (I think)

Comment: The answer from Thomas.W was very clear. I've marked it as an answer.

Comment: Lots of commands also have cheat sheets. Here is a decent list with options: http://www.inasp.info/uploads/filer_public/2014/08/29/linux_cheat_sheet_pdf.pdf

Comment: Very helpful document!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The acceptable flags for programs, and what those flags do, differ from program to program.  Because the `-v` or `-l` flags (or any flags, for that matter) will vary from program to program, it is best to read the manpages for each application to figure out what does what.

In your case, you specify `fdisk` and `shred`. Try reading the manpages for each.  (`man fdisk` and `man shred`)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple list of the arguments and what they do you can usually run `command --help`. Most commands show the most common or useful arguments (like `-l`) when run with `--help` or `-h`. The help page also shows what the command does. It would be useful if just want to know what the command does in one line instead of a whole paragraph.

While `man command` would show a lot more information. I find it easier to run it with the `--help` as it is easier to find what you are looking for quickly. You could use `command --help` if you already know what the command does and just need to look for the correct argument to use and `man command` when you want to know what the command does and a lot of other information not shown in the help page.

Some programs may not have the help page in which your only option would be to see the manpages.